# reading characters line by line from a text file in c with multiprocessing

Tags: c, file-io, multiprocessing, fseek

hi there i'm facing with `null` character problem while i'm reading and try to printing characters of a file with using `fseek()` function in a multiprocess programme. here is my simple code,

```
#include <stdio.h>     /* basic I/O routines.   */
#include <unistd.h>    /* define fork(), etc.   */
#include <sys/types.h> /* define pid_t, etc.    */
#include <sys/wait.h>  /* define wait(), etc.   */
#include <signal.h>    /* define signal(), etc. */
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

void print_screen(int i);
int counter=0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    FILE* fptr;
    fptr = fopen("sample.txt","w");

    int counter = atoi(argv[1]);
    int i,k;
    int temp;
    pid_t child_pid;
    int child_status;
    char array[counter];

    srand ( time(NULL) );

    for(i=0; i<counter; i++){
        temp = rand()%4;

        if( temp==0 ) {

            fprintf(fptr,"A\n");
            array[i]='A';
            }
        else if( temp==1 ) {

            fprintf(fptr,"C\n");
            array[i]='C';
            }
        else if( temp==2 ) {

            fprintf(fptr,"G\n");
            array[i]='G';
            }
        else if( temp==3 ) {

            fprintf(fptr,"T\n");
            array[i]='T';
            }
    }
    fclose(fptr);

                for(i=1; i<=counter; i++){

                    child_pid = fork();

                       switch(child_pid) {

                        case -1:
                            printf("Error occured with fork()\n");
                            exit(1);

                        case 0: 
                            print_screen(i); /* Child Process */
                            exit(0);
                             }
            }

    wait(&child_status);
    execl("/usr/bin/killall","killall","tail",(char *) 0);
    return 0;
}

void print_screen(int i){

    char* str;
    FILE* fptr;
    fptr=fopen("sample.txt","r");

        fseek(fptr,i,SEEK_SET);
        fscanf(fptr,"%s",str);
        printf("Process Number %d, Character = %s\n",i,str);
        sleep(1);

    fclose(fptr);
    return;
    }
```

Suppose that i enter `./sample 10` in to command line so programme will print 10 characters into sample.txt and then 10 child processes will be created, each of them try to pick a character and print onto the screen.moreover, as you can see i send `i` as a parameter to set the offset.but as i mentioned it prints null. this is the outlook the programme.

```
Process Number 7, Character = (null)
Process Number 6, Character = (null)
Process Number 5, Character = (null)
Process Number 3, Character = (null)
Process Number 8, Character = (null)
Process Number 4, Character = (null)
Process Number 9, Character = (null)
Process Number 10, Character = (null)
Process Number 2, Character = (null)
Process Number 1, Character = (null)
```

and the txt file was like this.

```
G
A
A
T
G
C
C
A
A
T
```

i will appreciated if you can help and thanks anyway.

edit: i realized that i compile like `$ gcc sample.c -o sample -lpthread` it prints out null. On the other hand, i compile it without `-lpthread` it prints character but not properly for example like this is the text file.

```
T
G
G
T
G
```

and terminal gives the output like this.

```
Process Number 1, Character = G
Process Number 2, Character = G
Process Number 3, Character = G
Process Number 4, Character = G
Process Number 5, Character = T
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~jcook/Tools/pthreads/pthreads.html

You propably know that a fork() produces a copy of the calling process and that this copy is (almost) identical to the original - they only differ in that fork() in the child = 1

Try (and tell me if its working, i could not test it :)

```
            for(i=1; i<=counter; i++){

                child_pid = fork();

                   switch(child_pid) {

                    case -1:
                        printf("Error occured with fork()\n");
                        exit(1);
                    case 0: 
                        print_screen(i); /* Child Process */
                        exit(0);
                    default: 
                        printf("...\n");
                         }
        }
```

EDIT: works for me

EDIT: okay i did some testing, should rather use `if` instead of `case` (also added dirext output of file content - should remove that if file size growth ); now thats what i had as code:

```
#include <stdio.h>     /* basic I/O routines.   */
#include <unistd.h>    /* define fork(), etc.   */
#include <sys/types.h> /* define pid_t, etc.    */
#include <sys/wait.h>  /* define wait(), etc.   */
#include <signal.h>    /* define signal(), etc. */
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

void print_screen(int i);
int counter=0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

FILE* fptr;
fptr = fopen("sample.txt","w");

int counter = atoi(argv[1]);
int i,k;
int temp;
pid_t child_pid;
int child_status;
char array[counter];

srand ( time(NULL) );

for(i=0; i<counter; i++){
    temp = rand()%4;

    if( temp==0 ) {

        fprintf(fptr,"A\n");
        printf("A\n");
        array[i]='A';
        }
    else if( temp==1 ) {

        fprintf(fptr,"C\n");
        printf("C\n");
        array[i]='C';
        }
    else if( temp==2 ) {
        fprintf(fptr,"G\n");
        printf("G\n");
        array[i]='G';
        }
    else if( temp==3 ) {
        fprintf(fptr,"T\n");
        printf("T\n");
        array[i]='T';
        }
}
fclose(fptr);
            for(i=1; i<=counter; i++){

                child_pid = fork();

                    if (child_pid == -1){
                        printf("Error occured with fork()\n"); exit(-1);
                    }
                    else if (child_pid == 0){
                         print_screen(i); exit(0);
                    }
                    else{ printf("something \n"); }
        }

wait(&child_status);
execl("/usr/bin/killall","killall","tail",(char *) 0);
return 0;
}

void print_screen(int i){

char* str;
FILE* fptr;
fptr=fopen("sample.txt","r");

    fseek(fptr,i,SEEK_SET);
    fscanf(fptr,"%s",str);
    printf("Process Number %d, Character = %s\n",i,str);
    sleep(1);

fclose(fptr);
return;
}
```

it doesnt work correct (i'm pretty sure there is some kind of collision when the pthreads are reading from the file at the same time) but at least you will have something to continue working with.

I got this output:

A

T

A

T

something

something

something

something

Process Number 4, Character = A

Process Number 3, Character = A

Process Number 2, Character = T

Process Number 1, Character = T

tail: no process found

Comment: it doesnt work for me, actually it stucks in a dead loop cause condition never be '1' actually. and i guess there is a wrong situation cause `child_pid` returns `0` when it is in child process and the parent should `default :` _? when i change it to default and set the child's condition to 0 it works but not properly. it prints wrong characters.

Comment: yeah thats what i mean!. it prints wrong series of characters.

Comment: as i said, its because the forked processes are all independent and there is nothing that controls the point in time when they print out the character they read. for example: p1 reads A, p2 reads B, p3 reads C, p2 prints B, p1 prints A, p3 prints C -> file is "A B C" but output is "B A C"

Comment: if it was work like that than there wouldn't be any problem. but the thing is the numbers of characters are not equal. for example when i run your code i got this input: 
`A
G
T
C
C`

and 
`Process Number 5, Character = C
Process Number 3, Character = T
Process Number 2, Character = G
Process Number 1, Character = G
Process Number 4, Character = T`

so there is no 'A' character which processes prints out

Answer (score 0):

You aren't allocating any memory for str in print_screen.  fscanf requires that.

Try a hack like:

```
void print_screen(int i){

char str[256];  /* plenty large enough for this example */
```